# How to ImportKey() to get CryptoObject from ExportedKey?

Tags: javascript, rsa, webcrypto-api

Trying to use the SubtleCrypto Web API to generate a public/private key pair, then use that keypair for encryption from a user inputting the public key, but `importKey()` keeps giving result as undefine. For public/private key generation, I have the following:

```
window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "RSA-OAEP",
        modulusLength: 2048, // can be 1024, 2048 or 4096
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
        hash: {name: "SHA-256"} // or SHA-512
    },
    true,
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
).then(function(keyPair) {

    console.log(keyPair);

    window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
        "pkcs8",
        keyPair.privateKey
    ).then(function(exportedPrivateKey) {
        // converting exported private key to PEM format
        var pem = toPem(exportedPrivateKey);
        console.log(pem);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
        "spki",
        keyPair.publicKey
    ).then(function(exportedPublicKey) {
        // converting exported private key to PEM format
        var pem = toPemP(exportedPublicKey);
        console.log(pem);
        let resultingKey = importPublicKey(pem)
        console.log('keyPairPublic: ', keyPair.publicKey)
        console.log('resultingKey: ', resultingKey)

    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

the `toPem()` and `toPemP()` functions are as follows:

```
function toPem(privateKey) {
    var b64 = addNewLines(arrayBufferToBase64(privateKey));
    var pem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" + b64 + "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    
    return pem;
}

function toPemP(publicKey) {
    var b64 = addNewLines(arrayBufferToBase64(publicKey));
    var pem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + b64 + "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    
    return pem;
}

function arrayBufferToBase64(arrayBuffer) {
    console.log('arrayBuffer', arrayBuffer);
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    var byteString = '';
    for(var i=0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
        byteString += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i]);
    }
    var b64 = window.btoa(byteString);

    return b64;
}

function addNewLines(str) {
    var finalString = '';
    while(str.length > 0) {
        finalString += str.substring(0, 64) + '\n';
        str = str.substring(64);
    }

    return finalString;
}
```

The importKey() function is as follows:

```
function importPublicKey(pem) {
    // base64 decode the string to get the binary data
    // fetch the part of the PEM string between header and footer
    const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
    const pemFooter = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    let pemContents = pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pem.length - pemFooter.length)
    pemContents = pemContents.replace(/\s/g, '');
    console.log('pemContents:', pemContents)
    let binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
    // convert from a binary string to an ArrayBuffer
    const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);
    console.log('binaryDer', binaryDer)

    window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "spki",
        binaryDer,
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP",
            hash: { name: "SHA-256" }
        },
        true,
        ["encrypt"]
    ).then(function(result) {
        return result;
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err: ', err);
    })
}
```

Where `str2ab()` is as follows:

```
function str2ab(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

All of the above functions were from the SubtleCrypto documentation. When I run the above, I get the following:

[image: Results of importKey()]

I'm not sure why it comes out as undefined, but I can notice that `arrayBuffer` and `binaryDer` don't have the exact same size. Don't know if it means anything and not sure how to fix this, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post the _full_ code, for instance what are the definitions of `arrayBufferToBase64()` and `addNewLines()`?

Comment: Didn't notice they weren't up, thank you!

Comment: This just looks like a bug in the structure of your JavaScript to me. Output the imported public key in `importPublicKey()` in the `then(function(result)` block before the `return` statement.

Comment: The code becomes clearer with async/await ([syntactic sugar for promises](https://medium.com/@matt.mcalister93/async-and-await-syntactic-sugar-for-promises-in-javascript-aee7ace36d14)): https://jsfiddle.net/omsyLhn3/

Comment: Outputting the result right before the return statement actually works!! I'm going to look at your jsfiddle now, thank you so so much!